# Why does Raphael use object[apply]?

Tags: javascript

I've been looking through the Raphael source – [source](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/raw/master/raphael.js)

They appear to use

```
object[apply](obj, args)
```

which I am assuming is equivalent to

```
object.apply(obj, args)
```

Am I assuming correctly? And if so why do they do this?

Thanks

**Edit**

As @deceze says apply is a variable and therefore it is not equivalent. However, on line 38 they assign the string `"apply"` to the variable `apply` so this makes it equivalent. Why would you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the dot notation is really just syntactic sugar for for `object[propertyname]`, but it has one disadvantage, the property name cannot be minified.

By doing

```
var apply = "apply";
foobar[apply](.....
foobar[apply](.....
foobar[apply](.....
foobar[apply](.....
```

this can actually be minified to

```
var a = "apply";
b[a](.....
b[a](.....
b[a](.....
b[a](.....
```

And there's your reason, Raphael uses the [] notation in order to provide better minification.

Answer (score 2):

In that case `apply` should be a variable which holds the name of a method, so this is a way of calling object methods with variable names. As such it is not equivalent to `object.apply()`, since this always calls the `apply()` method.

```
var apply = 'foo';
object[apply](); // calls object.foo()
```